# Can´t connect to remote server

Tags: powershell

I tried to send a mail like this:

```
Send-MailMessage -From x -Subject ads.log -To y -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -port 587 -Attachments $path\output.txt
```

But all I got is this response:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing? Or are there any rights restrictions?

Herer the full error message:

```
writeErrorStream: True
  Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Ke vzdálenému serveru se nelze připojit.
  TargetObject: System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
  CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
  FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
  ErrorDetails          : 
  InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
  ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\Documents\Powershell_project_1\search.ps1: line 27
  PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
```

Error message says "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: Show (and read) the **whole** errormessage, not just the bottom two lines

Comment: Do you have a company proxy in between?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need some kind of credentials to send emails via `smtp.office365.com` ?

Something like this:

```
$username="alone@home.com"
$password=ConvertTo-SecureString "XXXXX"-AsPlainText -Force
$mycredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
Send-MailMessage -To peterparker76@marvel.com -subject "Send from powerhell" -body "test from powerhell" -UseSsl -Port 587 -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -From $username -Credential $mycredentials
```

If you need more information about the error message you can always try `$error[0] | format-list -force`.